# Can you run the latest MySQL security update on macOS 10.12 Sierra?

Tags: macos, mysql

We're still running MySQL (community server) on macOS 10.12 Sierra (because Apple has gutted later versions of macOS and macOS Server and we don't want to go there just yet). It appears the latest MySQL security updates (October 2018) no longer support macOS with the 5.6.x track. The 5.7.x and 8.x tracks now only list installers for 10.13 High Sierra and 10.14 Mojave.

So, the **question** is: can you install the latest MySQL 5.7.24 on macOS 10.12 Sierra and will it run without problems?

I'm okay if it's simply "unsupported" and will install but if it specifically won't install/will cause problems I would like to know before upgrading. I've searched the MySQL web site for information on this but there is nothing.

I asked this question on the MySQL forums and got no response. I asked the question on StackOverflow but they recommended to post it here. Hope someone here can help.

Comment: Most likely it will work without problems - so why not just try it out? - You can always go back if it doesn't work like you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

No one bothered to reply (except for the idiot that suggested "why not just try it out?" for an in service, online, production server) but for those of you who may come across my original post I can now confirm, after extensive in-house testing, that MySQL 5.7.24 does NOT work on macOS 10.12 Sierra. It will spawn too many files for its process and eventually die requiring a full restart of the whole computer - you can't just kill and restart MySQL. With no security updates available for older versions of MySQL, this now makes MySQL useless on anything but macOS 10.13 High Sierra or later. Thus, given the awful state of macOS Server, your days of running a decent macOS Server with MySQL are now numbered. Time to start testing alternate operating systems and switch…